# How to notify user caps lock is turned on within a password field in C#?

Tags: visual-studio, validation

I'm not a pro, but What i want in my Login panel (a windows form) which hass a pasword Text field,

I want to apply the same idea here, 'window Xp password text field had', in which if Caps lock is on, a small String gets to Popup saying CAPSLOCK is On, `

```
private void txtPass_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtPass.PasswordChar= '*' ;
    }
```

`

this is my Password button.

Answer (score 0):

The magic happens in this line

```
 Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

If this line is missing then you loose that functionality together with the flat appearance of many controls and so on.

The line should go before any attempt to create user interface objects and usually is present in the Main static method that starts your application

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
     Application.Run(new yourStartupForm());
}
```